# Magento 2 static content deploy error less

Tags: magento2, less-css, compilation

I Got this error in compilation

```
[Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException]
```

**Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/html/saaf/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/li

  b/Less/Functions.php on line 28**

Don't know how to resolve this error.

Comment: remove var folder and try again deploy command

Comment: Done this process again, but still showing the same error.

Comment: Resolved Error,
It occurs due to a plugin CSS which I included in my project having a shorthand property ** font:0/0 a ** which is not supported in Magento 2 less compilation.

Comment: you can add as answer for your question

Answer (score 3):

Resolved Error, It occurs due to a plugin CSS which I included in my project having a shorthand property **font:0/0 a** which is not supported in Magento 2 less compilation causes a **warning** "Division by zero".

Comment: You can escape this kind on operators on less like this: `font:~'0/0' a` so less doesn't think you're trying to divide by zero.